# Checking if SQL Server database is running in MULTI_USER mode

Tags: sql-server

How can I check what mode a particular database is in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try using the [`DATABASEPROPERTYEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823.aspx)

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('databasename','UserAccess')
```

if the database is in multi_user mode must return `MULTI_USER`

Comment: nice one. I reckon this way faster than mine.

Answer (score 2):

use [sp_dboption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933268(SQL.80).aspx) like this

```
EXEC sp_dboption 'DB_NAME', 'single user'
```

*to set it add the option third parameter. See below*

[image]

Comment: Does that not set it? I want to report back on it's current state (because I am not convinced setting it to multi_user has worked.)

Comment: I did not know that, thought you could only set things with it, thanks for the answer but as you say in another comment, there is a quicker way.